# how to remove shade on compose view?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-jetpack-compose

I use compose button in android view, but there is some shade at the bottom. How can I remove it?

```
    @Composable
fun VisibilityAnimationFAB() {
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    FloatingActionButton(
        onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
        modifier = Modifier
    ) {
        Row(Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp)) {
            Icon(
                vectorResource(id = R.drawable.ic_twitter),
                Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            )
            AnimatedVisibility(
                expanded,
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
            ) {
                androidx.compose.material.Text(modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp), text = "Tweet")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **`elevation`** attribute in the `FloatingActionButton`

```
FloatingActionButton(
        onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
        modifier = Modifier,
        elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(0.dp,0.dp)
    ){ /* .. */ }
```

Answer (score 5):

Use the `elevation` parameter in `FloatingActionButton`. In material design, elevation is the relative distance between two surfaces along the z-axis. Shadows make differences in surface elevation perceptible. ([source](https://material.io/design/environment/elevation.html#depicting-elevation))

You have to pass [`FloatingActionButtonElevation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/FloatingActionButtonElevation), which can be created using the [`elevation(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/FloatingActionButtonDefaults#elevation(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,%20androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) method.

```kotlin
FloatingActionButton(
  elevation = elevation(
    defaultElevation = 0.dp
    pressedElevation = 0.dp
  ),
  // ...
) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this code disable all shadows

```
    FloatingActionButton(
        onClick = { expanded = !expanded },
        modifier = Modifier,
        elevation = null
    )
```

Comment: Thank you!! This one worked perfectly! `elevation = null`

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = {},              
            elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(
                defaultElevation = 0.dp
            )
        )
```